# I don't understand what is the meaning of the Error

Tags: python-2.7

After running the following code, I got this error. But I don't know what the error means and how to solve it?

code with the error :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed multiplying (*) after (h), which python is considering as function which is obviously not found. Change the code in line number to below code

---

```
volume = 1/3 * 22/7 * h * (R1*R1 +R2*R2 +R1*R2)
```